# Check if a FocusEvent was caused by tab losing focus

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

How, if possible, would I check if an input has lost focus because of a tab switch/window lost focus.

Usecase: I am resetting a form on blur and would like to make the data persist if a user merely switches tabs or the window loses focus

I am aware that I could instead just check for a click event happening outside the input but I would also like to include the possibility of a user tabbing out of the form which is why I have the handle attache to the general blur event.

Comment: you can perhaps catch `onmousedown` of document and set flag if the key code is tab? Then the `onblur` can act accordingly to the set flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to acheive this using `document.hasFocus`.

e.g code:

```
 handleBlur = () => {
    if (!document.hasFocus()) {
      return;
    }

    this.deactivate()
  };
```